# Отступ в поле ввода и скрытие символов

Tags: html, css, frontend

Как сделать так, чтобы ввод начинался с отступа?

Как сделать срытие текста при вводе пароля?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: выложите Ваш код, тогда Вам смогут помочь более детально.Ответ AlexDevTime верен.

Answer (score 1):

1. Сделать у `input` отступ с помощью CSS свойства `padding`.
2. Сделать у `input` скрытие текста, задав значение атрибуту `type="password"`.